# Google drive picker in flutter

Tags: flutter, flutter-dependencies, dart-pub

I want to open google drive from device and select file from it and display file in flutter app.

[file_picker](https://pub.dev/packages/file_picker) has feature like Pick files from cloud files (GDrive, Dropbox, iCloud) but i can't figure out using file picker how can i open google drive and pick file from it.

Please suggest me using file_picker package how to open google drive or is there any other way to achieve it?